# Android Binary converter trouble

Tags: java, android, textview

Hello
 I just finished my first app and I ran into a little problem to say the least it complies just fine but when I press enter and clicking text to binary it goes crazy I have narrowed the problem down to

```
textview1.setText(binary);
```

Any help is appreciated and sorry if my code is a little sloppy thats one of the many things I need to work on.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Binary extends Activity {

    Button b1 ;
    EditText edittext;
    RadioButton rad1, rad2;
    TextView textview1 ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        rad1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rad1);
        rad2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rad2);
           }


    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if(rad1.isChecked())
           {
               String s1 = edittext.getText().toString();
               byte[] bytes = s1.getBytes();
               StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
               for (byte b : bytes)
                  {
                     int val = b;
                     for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                     {
                        binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
                        val <<= 1;
                     }
                     binary.append(' ');
                  }

                textview1.setText(binary);


            }
        }
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
android:id="@+id/widget92"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/edittext"
android:layout_width="264px"
android:layout_height="57px"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:autoText="true"
android:layout_x="30px"
android:layout_y="36px"
>
</EditText>
<RadioGroup
android:id="@+id/rg1"
android:layout_width="260px"
android:layout_height="42px"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_x="33px"
android:layout_y="116px"
>
<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/rad1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Text to Binary"
>
</RadioButton>
<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/rad2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Binary to Text"
>
</RadioButton>
</RadioGroup>
<Button
android:id="@+id/b1"
android:layout_width="142px"
android:layout_height="55px"
android:text="Enter"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_x="85px"
android:layout_y="208px"
android:onClick="onClick"
>
</Button>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textview1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:layout_x="115px"
android:layout_y="288px"
>
</TextView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: you can post your error message or log first.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about your problem than "it goes crazy"?

Comment: it gives me the application  has stopped unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

```
int val = b;
```

should be

```
int val = b - '0'; // Character.getNumericValue(b);
```

**NOTE**: ASCII value of `0` is 48(in decimal). so `0` to `9` will be `48` to `57`. so you need to subtract `48`, that is `'0'`, from the byte which has values between 48 and 57(inclusive).

Comment: ty could you explain to me why its int val = b - '0';

Comment: @user705282: ascii value of `0` is 48. so `0` to `9` will be `48` to `57`. so you need to subtract `48`, that is `'0'`, from the byte which has values between 48 and 57.